# How does the ternary C operator interpret an empty 1st branch? Why?

Tags: c, gcc, conditional-operator

This seems to compile and run without warnings using `gcc -Wall` (4.9.2)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("%d\n", argc-1?:42);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run it

- with 0 args (making `argc-1` evaluate to `false`), it prints `42`;
- with n>=1 args (making `argc-1` evaluate to `true`), it prints n-1.

Am I right if I assume that `x?:y` is in this case equivalent to `x?x:y`? Is this standard, expected behaviour, or just a GCC quirk?

Comment: Ouch - only too late I find that this is a dupe. I searched around, honest.

Comment: _"with 1 or more (making argc-1 evaluate to true), it prints 1"_ No it doesn't, it prints `(argc-1)`, e.g. with 4 arguments it prints 4, with 42 arguments it prints 42. Because `(argc-1)` is an `int` not a boolean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a known [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html) for the shorthand version of the conditional operator.

```
 argc-1?:42
```

is just the same as

```
(argc-1)?(argc-1):42
```

The reason for using this variation is (and I Quote)

> *"When it becomes useful is when the first operand does, or may (if it is a macro argument), contain a side effect. Then repeating the operand in the middle would perform the side effect twice. Omitting the middle operand uses the value already computed without the undesirable effects of recomputing it."*

Comment: But is the program runs with no argument ``argc`` will be 1, then the program should return ``0`` not ``1``, no ?

Comment: Nitpick : it is the same, except that the expression used as both the condition and the first operand is evaluated only once.

Comment: @ibi0tux so you mean to say, then the condition will be TRUE? how is that?

Comment: @Quentin expanded the answer.